# Complicated bar graph for measurements in z dimension and time

Tags: matlab, graph

I am writing code to analyze data that for each data point there is a value, a vertical z dimension height associated with it, and the time at which it was taken.  I would like to have a bar graph that contains all this information.  The measurements are taken for a large interval of time at one height, then move down to the next height, then the next, then back up again.  So I want the bar graph to reflect the height change by plotting the measurement displayed in time at three different levels on the y axis.  I have stored the heights, time, and measurements in a structured array.

I don't have the reputation yet to post pictures, but here is a sketch:

```
.....|....||||...||........................|||||||.................................................................................................................
.....|....|||||||||........................|||||||.................................................................................................................    
.....|....|||||||||........................|||||||.................................................................................................................
.....|................||..||.......................................................................................................................................
.....|................|||||||.......................................................................................................................................
.....|............................|||||||...........................................................................................................................
     _________________________________________________
```

This is what I've tried:

```
for i = 11:numel(MARbckDATA.averageDepth)
    y = -1*MARbckDATA.averageDepth(i)  

    figure(3); 

bar(MARbckDATA.seconds(i), (-1*MARbckDATA.averageDepth(i)) + (MARbckDATA.area(i)), 'BaseValue',y);

 hold on

end
```

However, the x axis only has the last time in it. Why is this, and what's the proper way to do it?